# Displaying date in a double digit format - java

Tags: java

Instead for example "9/1/1996" I want my code to display "09/01/1996". I don't know how to describe my question more specific. Here is my code for the MyDate class:

```
public class MyDate {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public MyDate(int y, int m, int d){
        year = y;
        month = m;
        day = d;

        System.out.printf("I'm born at: %s\n", this);
    }

    public  String toString(){
        return String.format("%d/%d/%d", year, month,  day);
    }
  }
```

And here  is my main method:

```
public class MyDateTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MyDate birthday = new MyDate(31,12,1995);
    }

}
```

p.s I know that there is a way with importing calendar, but I rather doing it this way.

Comment: *Why* would rather reinvent the wheel? I'd suggest you use java.time.* or Joda Time rather than Date/Calendar, but I'd strongly recommend against reimplementing this yourself unless you really, really have to.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't see the harm as long as it is for learning.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Well, as long as the OP then uses the right tool for the job in the real world. I have no problem with curiosity of course - but you need to know where to draw the line.

Answer (score 3):

According to your problem it seems you are using customized class for date. But you can use inbuilt `java.util.Date` class for any kind of Date represent or compare. So you can use `DateFormat` to display formatted date time. Consider the following example.

```
    Date date = //code to get your date

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
13/10/2015
```

**Additionally you there you should specify the pattern for your `DateFormat`. Use following table for date formatting characters.**

[image]

**If you are still need to use your magic `MyDate` class**

You can use `System.out.printf` specified with leading zeros as follows.

```
System.out.printf("%02d/%02d/%04d", date, month, year);
```

Comment: "But you can use inbuilt java.util.Date class for any kind of Date calculation" - no, you can use `Date` for almost *no* date calculations, partly because it's been so badly designed and partly because it only represents an instant in time, not in any particular calendar or time zone. You can use java.util.Calendar for most date calculations, but you'd be better off using Joda Time or java.time.*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a number formatting question. Before the 'd' in %d, you can put the length of the number field, and if you want leading zeros instead of leading spaces, then you add a '0' in front of that. So a 2-digit number field with leading zeros is `%02d`.

So your code becomes:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%04d/%02d/%02d", year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.format("%d/%02d/%02d", year, month,  day)
```

String format the output.

Answer (score 1):

you should import also this `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.text.DateFormat;` when using

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your format string for `String.format` to pad with leading zeros:

```
return String.format("%d/%02d/%02d", year, month,  day);
```

- `0` means pad the output with leading zeros
- `2` means the output should be 2 characters wide (day and month)
- year should not need a modifier since it will always be 4 digits (at least for the next 8 millennia)

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/QsQKpa)

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks a lot))